Two capacitively coupled LC circuits: where did I make the mistake?
Problem:
I have an issue obtaining the correct circuit equations for these coupled LC circuits.

Attempted solution:
We obtain the equations of motion for the capacitors by using Kirchoff's law for a loop on the left and on the right
\begin{align}
    \text{Voltage loops: }&\begin{cases} 
      V_{C_1} + V_{L_1} = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 \dot{I}_1 = 0 \\
      V_{C_2} + V_{L_2} = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2\dot{I}_4 = 0
   \end{cases}\notag\\
    \text{Current junctions: }&\begin{cases} 
        I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \\
        I_2 = I_4 + I_5. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{align}
We use the current junction conditions to write \$I_1\$ and  \$I_4\$ in terms of the capacitors charge, this leaves the voltage conditions
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\dot{I}_2 + \dot{I}_3) = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(\dot{I}_2 - \dot{I}_5) = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
Note that we can eliminate \$Q_g\$ by charge conservation, \$Q_g = Q_1 - Q_2\$ (IS THIS THE MISTAKE?)
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (2\ddot{Q}_1 - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(2\ddot{Q}_2 - \ddot{Q}_1) = 0.
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
...?
Correct answer (without me understanding my mistake):
I know the Lagrangian should have been
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}L_1\dot{Q}_1^2  - \frac{1}{2C_1}Q_1^2  + \frac{1}{2}L_2\dot{Q}_2^2 - \frac{1}{2C_2}Q_2^2 + C_g(\dot{Q}_1 - \dot{Q}_2)^2,
\end{equation}
which doesn't yield my circuit equations hence there's a mistake somewhere!
For the record, with this Lagrangian, you yield
$$L_1 \ddot{Q_1} + 2C_g(\ddot{Q_1} -\ddot{Q_2}) + \frac{1}{C_1}Q_1 = 0$$
and
$$L_2 \ddot{Q_2}  +2C_g(\ddot{Q_2} -\ddot{Q_1}) + \frac{1}{C_2}Q_2= 0$$
by the Euler-Lagrange equations. Apparently, those are the ones I should obtain above with Kirchoff.

It seems you are using kvl or kcl in your way. It may be better to write mesh equations when using mesh analysis or nodal equations when using nodal analysis. They are easier than finding individual currents in other ways. Avoid differential equations unless you are finding transient currents or voltages. Are you trying to find transient currents or steady state currents?.

@AmitM Transient currents. I need to know the dynamics of it all! Can you elaborate? did you spot a mistake?

There is no power source. Where are the initial conditions such as current in any inductor at $ t=0^+$ or voltage in a capacitor at  $ t=0^+$ ?  You need initial conditions for all components to write differential equation or to solve them by laplace transform. With initial conditions any of the inductors or capacitors would become an energy source to write KVL and KCL equations. They are necessary to do this problem.

Three  errors: 1) missing initial conditions on each part 2) missing time/frequency domain analysis 3) assuming Q is constant which is always modulating in this lossless 5th order circuit which has at least 2 dominant poles. https://tinyurl.com/2yv8nqj8

What are the correct circuit equations you are aiming to derive?

@D.A.S. and AmitM  1) You absolutely don't need initial conditions to propose a differential equation, only to find a particular solution to it. 2) I don't understand what you mean, perhaps it's related to 3) Q is not constant, it is instead the function I wish to solve the equations for. Why would I take derivatives of Q wrt time ?

@Andyaka Well, knowing the last lagrangian is correct, those would be $L_1 \ddot{Q_1} + 2C_g(\ddot{Q_1} -\ddot{Q_2}) + \frac{1}{C_1}Q_1 = 0$ by the Euler-Lagrange eq. Similarly, you would also yield wrt $Q_2$, $L_2 \ddot{Q_2}  +2C_g(\ddot{Q_2} -\ddot{Q_1}) + \frac{1}{C_2}Q_2= 0$. Added this to the main questionl.

@FriendlyLagrangian I haven't looked over your work yet. But it is rare to discuss Lagrangians and Hamiltonians and Legendre transformations here. For some, a little nomenclature context may help. Also, there is graph theory, linear algebra, and the KCL and KVL nullspace concepts, plus the rank-nullity theorem to consider on the path. Perhaps.

@FriendlyLagrangian, if you dont need initiial conditions, you seem to try to derive the equations such as   transfer funtion for this filter. It may not be a particular filter because by changing L C values, it may change from one type of filter or another.

I really don't want to come across as being rude but I thought the question was simple: can anyone derive the Kirchoff equations for the charges in the capacitors? Alternatively, since $Q = \int I(t)dt $, can anyone derive the currents across the capacitors? I would also be content with any other Kirchoff law application, since I am clearly making a mistake in this somewhere. I keep reading technical terms in the comments being thrown around as if this was a complex task but it should be simple no? just two LC oscillators together!

When you connect two LC oscillators with a cap, you only have one 5th order complex oscillator with at least 2 side bands closest to the f with lowest impedance. The higher impedance tank spreads the sidebands. The initial currents, voltages and thus charge in each tank are loaded by the tank with the lowest Z(f). Therefore initial conditions do matter and nothing from Kirchoff’s laws will describe this behaviour.  The total charge in the circuit depends on the initial charge in each element, this init.cond. should matter.
What do you want to see for an output?

The closest treatment of this circuit I found here…. On p11 called “Fast multiplexed superconducting qubit readout with intrinsic Purcell filtering” on ResearchGate using Hamiltonians

https://jfuchs.hotell.kau.se/kurs/amek/prst/15_ldec.pdf

I found the answer to my question, it really isn't as complicated as people here suggest. Let me share it here for the future learners.

First of all, indeed \$Q_g = Q_1 - Q_2\$ or any similar reasoning is incorrect. However, the rest of the equations were well posed. Let me reproduce them here in addition with the final missing step:
I want to find the charge \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ to quantise the problem. My guess for the Kirchhoff voltage loops and current equations  would be
\begin{align}
    \text{Voltage loops: }&\begin{cases} 
      V_{C_1} + V_{L_1} = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 \dot{I}_1 = 0 \\
      V_{C_2} + V_{L_2} = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2\dot{I}_4 = 0
   \end{cases}\notag\\
    \text{Current junctions: }&\begin{cases} 
        I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \\
        I_2 = I_4 + I_5. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{align}
And by using the current junction conditions we can write \$I_1\$ and  \$I_4\$ in terms of the capacitors charge:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\dot{I}_2 + \dot{I}_3) = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(\dot{I}_2 - \dot{I}_5) = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
Now, I want to eliminate \$Q_g\$ since I'm only interested in \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. For this, we can read off one more loop equation for the loop concerning only the capacitors. This is
$$\frac{Q_2}{C_2} + \frac{Q_g}{C_g} - \frac{Q_1}{C_1} = 0, $$
which is the correct expression for the charge conservation. With this we  yield
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1)=\frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1\ddot{Q}_1  +  C_g L_1(\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) =\frac{1}{C_2} Q_{2} + L_2\ddot{Q}_2  +  C_g L_2(\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} )= 0, 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
which can of course be symetrised a bit by dividing
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{L_1 C_1} Q_{1} + \ddot{Q}_1  +  C_g (\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{C_2 L_2} Q_{2} + \ddot{Q}_2  +  C_g(\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} )= 0. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
It will be easier to work instead with the variable \$\Phi_n = Q_n/C_n \$ instead so that we can read off the lagrangian easierly. With that we have
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{L_1} \Phi_{1} + C_1 \ddot{\Phi}_1  +  C_g(\ddot{\Phi}_1  -\ddot{\Phi}_2  ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{ L_2} \Phi_{2} + C_2 \ddot{\Phi}_2  +  C_g(\ddot{\Phi}_2  -\ddot{\Phi}_1  )= 0, 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
with which we reverse engenieer the Lagrangian to be
$$ \mathcal{L}(\Phi_1,\Phi_2;\dot{\Phi}_1,\dot{\Phi}_2) = \frac{C_1}{2}\dot{\Phi}_1^2 -  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{C_2}{2}\dot{\Phi}_2^2 -  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_2^2}{L_2} + \frac{C_g}{2}\left(\dot{\Phi}_1 - \dot{\Phi}_2 \right)^2, $$
as desired.

Quantasing the problem is now trivial, we perform a Legendre transformation to obtain the Hamiltonian
$$  \mathcal{H} = \sum_n\left( \dot{\Phi_n} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\Phi_n}}\right)  - \mathcal{L}  =  \frac{C_1}{2}\dot{\Phi}_1^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{C_2}{2}\dot{\Phi}_2^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_2^2}{L_2}  + \frac{C_g}{2}(\dot{\Phi}_1 - \dot{\Phi}_2 )^2$$
which written in terms of canonical operators, \$ p_n \doteq \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\Phi_n}} = C_n \dot{\Phi}_n \$,  is simply
$$  \mathcal{H} =   \frac{1}{2C_1}p_1^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{1}{2C_2}p_2^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_2^2}{L_2}  + \frac{C_g}{2}\left(\frac{p_1}{C_1} - \frac{p_2}{C_2} \right)^2, \quad \text{together with} \quad [x,p] = i.$$
We now define bosonic creation and annihilation operators,
$$ x_n = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_n}{2}}(a^\dagger_n + a_n), \quad p_n = i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \lambda_n}}(a^\dagger_n - a_n),$$
these satisfy \$[a_n,a^\dagger_n] = 1\$ (all other commutators vanishes) and leaves us the freedom to choose \$\lambda_n \$ wisely. A wise choice for the diagonalisation is \$\lambda_n = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} \$. With this, we have
$$ \mathcal{H} =   \sum_n \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{L_nC_n}} (a^\dagger_n a_n +1) + \frac{C_g}{2}\left(\frac{p_1}{C_1} - \frac{p_2}{C_2} \right)^2 $$
etc
